# Logstash Indexing Error - Aggregate plugin: For task_id pattern '%{id}', there are more than one filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Am using Elasticsearch 5.5.0 and logstash 5.5.0 on Linux - AWS ec2-instance.

Have a logstash_etl.conf file which resides in /etc/logstash/conf.d:

```
input {
     jdbc {
         jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"
         jdbc_user => "root"
         jdbc_password => ""
         jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/mysql-connector/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"
         jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.driver"
         schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
         statement => "select * from customers"
         use_column_value => false
         clean_run => true
     }
  }

 filter {
    if ([api_key]) {
      aggregate {
        task_id => "%{id}"
        push_map_as_event_on_timeout => false
        #timeout_task_id_field => "[@metadata][index_id]"
        #timeout => 60 
        #inactivity_timeout => 30
        code => "sample code"
        timeout_code => "sample code"
      }
    }
  }

  # sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-exec
  output {
     if ([purge_task] == "yes") {
       exec {
           command => "curl -XPOST '127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
               {
                 \"query\": {
                   \"range\" : {
                     \"@timestamp\" : {
                       \"lte\" : \"now-3h\"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
           '"
       }
     } else {
         stdout { codec => json_lines}
         elasticsearch {
            "hosts" => "127.0.0.1:9200"
            "index" => "myindex_%{api_key}"
            "document_type" => "%{[@metadata][index_type]}"
            "document_id" => "%{[@metadata][index_id]}"
            "doc_as_upsert" => true
            "action" => "update"
            "retry_on_conflict" => 7
         }
     }
  }
```

When I restart logstash like this:

```
sudo initctl restart logstash
```

Inside /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log - everything works an actual indexing into Elasticsearch is occuring!

However if I add another SQL input into this config file:

```
input {
     jdbc {
         jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"
         jdbc_user => "root"
         jdbc_password => ""
         jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/mysql-connector/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"
         jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.driver"
         schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
         statement => "select * from orders"
         use_column_value => false
         clean_run => true
     }
  }
```

The indexing stops because of an error inside the config file!

Inside /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log:

```
[2018-04-06T21:33:54,123][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Aggregate plugin: For task_id pattern '%{id}', there are more than one filter which defines timeout options. All timeout options have to be defined in only one aggregate filter per task_id pattern. Timeout options are : timeout, inactivity_timeout, timeout_code, push_map_as_event_on_timeout, push_previous_map_as_event, timeout_task_id_field, timeout_tags>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-aggregate-2.6.1/lib/logstash/filters/aggregate.rb:486:in `register'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-aggregate-2.6.1/lib/logstash/filters/aggregate.rb:480:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:281:in `register_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:292:in `register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:292:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:302:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:226:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:398:in `start_pipeline'"]}
[2018-04-06T21:33:54,146][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-04-06T21:33:57,131][WARN ][logstash.agent ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Am really new to logstash and Elasticsearch...

What does this mean?

Would appreciate if someone could tell me why by just by adding one new input causes this tool to crash?!

Comment: Can you clarify that you have a single `input` section with two `jdbc` sub-sections and not two `input` sections each with one `jdbc` sub-sections?

Comment: Also are you sure that you have a single logstash configuration file or did you copy/paste the first one to create the second pipeline?

Comment: So my guess is that you are using `nano` or `vim` or `gedit`. In case `nano` it creates a backup file and in case of vim it can leave a temporary file. So your editor is causing a backup file to be created which is getting double loaded into the config. I would do a `ls -alh  /etc/logstash/conf.d` to make sure there only files you intend to see. I have seen such issues with `nginx` and I assume your case might be the same

Comment: Any input @PacificNW_Lover ?

Answer (score 1):

> Would appreciate if someone could tell me why by just by adding one new input causes this tool to crash?!

You can't add two `input` statement inside the same configuration. Like the [documentation says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html), if you want to add more than one `input` in a config file, you should use something like that:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/messages"
    type => "syslog"
  }

  file {
    path => "/var/log/apache/access.log"
    type => "apache"
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, even though I read this `However if I add another SQL input into this config file` I still didn't catch that he said adding this to the same config file, I just assumed he is making another file